# Sencha Touch setTimeout(function, timeoutNumber) not working

Tags: sencha-touch

The setTimeout() function in Sencha Touch does not work. It executes the code immediately as setTimeout is called. Has anybody had experience / has a workaround for this bug?

Comment: `setTimeout` should work just fine in ST. Can you give some example code? What version of ST? 1.1 or 2?

Comment: Just checked in the sencha libraries and apparently I'm using 1.0.... Whoops, still have to upgrade that to 1.1... Should be interesting. Example code as follows:       `var mapTimeout = setTimeout(evaluateMap(), 15000)`        `evaluateMap: function(){//do something}`

Comment: You want `setTimeout(evaluateMap, 15000)`, you want to hand setTimeout a reference to your function, instead you are executing it and giving setTimeout whatever the function returns.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [Ext.Functions.defer](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Function-method-defer); (Short: Ext.defer)

```
// this syntax is sometimes useful for deferring execution of an anonymous function:
Ext.defer(function(){}, millisecs, scope);

// defer the answer 100ms with the current scope
Ext.defer(function() {
    alert('Anonymous');
}, 100, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Defer is the variant of SetTimeout function in Sencha

```
Ext.Function.defer(function () {
    alert('Anonymous');
}, 5000);
```